# Angularjs - Page goes Blank when working with ng-show for two different links

Tags: angularjs, local-storage, ng-show

Link1 : Profile

Link2 : Update

view : common.html

This two link is part of home.html

So, in my application Both profile and Update will redirect to common.html.With the help of ng-show I m showing certain part on click of link.

This is an example of mycode. In actual scenario, view is stored on different path in view/common.html

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.get = function(d) {
        if (d == 1) {
            $scope.pro = true;
            $scope.set = false;
        } else if (d == 2) {
            $scope.set = true;
            $scope.pro = false;

        }
    }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <div ng-click="get(1)">Profile</div>
    <div ng-click="get(2)">Setting</div>

    <div ng-show="pro"> This is my profile </div>
    <div ng-show="set"> This is my settting </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Problem:
While I refresh the page, Page goes blank.

What I want is if I clicked on either of link and then refresh then it should show respective page where I was present.I try to achieve this through localstorage, by setting unique id in localstorage for both link.

But I m not getting how to achieve this.Help me for this.

Comment: set `pro` or `set` as defualt page in controller. by `$scope.pro=true; $scope.set = false;`

Comment: it one of the solution. But if I want to show that particular page on which user is currently present, then what the solution for this?  @hadiJz

Comment: When you reload the page, scope.set and scope.pro are undefined!! So that's totally normal because angular ng-show condition is not true!!

Comment: What you really want to do?? What default behaviour you want to implement?

Comment: bydefault if should show the page I am visted. If I am on setting page then it should show setting page after reloaf and same for profile one. I think we can implement it with local storage, But how I am not getting that. @Sphinx117

Comment: Why do u want to refresh? You can keep it in same page or use angular routing.

Comment: actually its one of the case, User visted the setting page then it might b case witherhe will fill data or he can refresh too. That is why I am trying to solve this refresh part.  @RaviShankar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller only contains one `get` function and nothing else, so when the controller is run, both `pro` and `set` have a value of `undefined`.

Since in JavaScript `undefined` has a falsy value, ng-show hides both pages. You'll have to set a default page to show by setting that value as true in your controller:

```
(function() {
    angular.module("myApp", [])
        .controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

            // set default values
            $scope.pro = true;
            $scope.set = false;

            $scope.get = function(d) {
                if (d == 1) {
                    $scope.pro = true;
                    $scope.set = false;
                } else if (d == 2) {
                    $scope.set = true;
                    $scope.pro = false;

                }
            };

        });
})();
```

Comment: @Mohammed I've added a few more things in your controller. Firstly, there's an IIFE(read up on that) and I've removed the app variable(there's really no need for yet another global variable floating around in your app when you can just as easily fetch your app using getters). Thirdly, just read up on ngRoute or ui.router Angular modules and use one of those: they're way more powerful than what you're doing now.

Comment: Cant we use localstorage for setting the page instead of default page, IF YES,  then please help me for this.  @cst1992

Comment: no. I will let you know, once I will done that. @cst1992

Answer (score 0):

In your get function register the value of set and pro in local storage.

In your controller initialise your variables with the session storage if they are defined. That's all.

Maybe you should use 
$locationChangeStart
Broadcasted before a URL will change.

So before url change save in session storage the current tab. Google it!